# Ubuntu - how to unpackage gcc?

Tags: gcc

I am trying to unpackage "gcc-4.4_4.4.3.orig.tar.gz." After reading 5 sites from Google to do the unpackage, I cannot figure it out.

Please tell me how to unpackage "gcc-4.4_4.4.3.orig.tar.gz."

thanks

Comment: http://launchpadlibrarian.net/38192173/gcc-4.4_4.4.3.orig.tar.gz

Comment: Then download it from the link given bellow.

Comment: that package is unofficial, get an official package from gcc.org

Comment: thanks Dustin and Cedric - here's the link:

ftp://ftp.mirrorservice.org/sites/sourceware.org/pub/gcc/releases/gcc-4.4.3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tar xzvf gcc-4.4_4.4.3.orig.tar.gz
```

for a gziped file (like .tar.gz)

and

```
tar xJvf gcc-4.4_4.4.3.orig.tar.xz
```

for a file like .tar.xz

Comment: After I run your command (thank you, by the way), this folder now exists:

gcc-4.4_4.4.3.orig/gcc-4.4.3.tar.xz

Comment: @Cedric H.: `tar -xzvf gcc-4.4_4.4.3.orig.tar.gz` I'd say. (you missed the `-` at the beginning, denoting a parameter)

Comment: Piskvor, I typed it in again very carefully. Same thing occurs:

tar xzvf gcc-4.4_4.4.3.orig.tar.gz creates a new directory and file: .....................................................
gcc-4.4_4.4.3.orig/gcc-4.4_4.4.3.tar.xz

Comment: @Piskvor: it works without the minus sign
@Kevin: run the same command on the newly created file ?

Comment: @Cedric: error - output: gzip: stdin: not in gzip format \n tar: Child returned status 1 \n tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors

Comment: output: "tar: invalid option -- J"

Comment: Then you need something else to extract from that (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xz).

But maybe you can download another clean gcc (http://gcc.gnu.org/mirrors.html).

Comment: Nothing is wrong here. extracting gcc-4.4_4.4.3.orig.tar.gz yields gcc-4.4_4.4.3.orig/gcc-4.4_4.4.3.tar.xz among other things. Just extract that too.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of remembering the flag to select a compression type when extracting an archive, you can let GNU tar (version >= 1.20) autodetect it for you. Example:

```
tar xf archive.tar.gz
tar xf archive.tar.bz2
tar xf archive.tar.xz
```

The same thing of course works for listing an archive as well:

```
tar tf archive.tar.gz
tar tf archive.tar.bz2
tar tf archive.tar.xz
```

To create an archive, you can use the `-a` (or `--auto-compress`) flag, which makes tar use the file suffix to do the right thing:

```
tar caf archive.tar.gz file ...
tar caf archive.tar.bz2 file ...
tar caf archive.tar.xz file ...
```

Answer (score 0):

i dunno where you got that file, but XZ extraction is:

`tar Jxf gcc-4.4.3.tar.xz`

Comment: output: "tar: invalid option -- J"

Comment: your system is out of date and doesn't support XZ. go download an official tar.gz from gcc.org